# my curl process is downloading, then overwriting the files

Tags: c#, curl, process

I'm using `Process` to start a curl binary and download some urls on windows. I'm finding that one url (poss more) is downloaded and written to disk, then instantly overwritten with a filesize of 0, then written again. Why is this? Is it linked to my use of `-O` three times? (I'm grabbing three urls) It's the only way I've found to write the files to disk as `remote-name-all` doesn't appear to do anything. I'm using a curl binary version 7.53.1, which according to the docs will have `remote-name-all`

My Process start Info:

```
        _p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = _config.PathToCurlBinary,
            Arguments = $"{urls} {args}", // urls are space separated
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false, // should this be true?,
            WorkingDirectory = _config.OutputDirectory
        };
```

and my curl arguments:

```
var args = $"--silent --compressed --connect-timeout 100 --user-agent \"{_config.UserAgent}\" --location" +
$" -O -O -O --retry 25 --retry-connrefused --stderr error.log" +                                                                    
$" --cookie-jar \"{cookieFileName}\"";
```

Comment: Print out $"{urls} {args}" and run the output on the command line manually. See what you get.

Comment: @OwenPauling it downloads as expected without overwriting.